# Patching Magento SUPEE-5345 Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, nginx, patch

I'm trying to install the latest patch on Magento 1.7.0.2 running on a centOS nginx server. I've installed it on the dev server via SSH and all worked smoothly. However the live server which is nginx I'm getting this error:

```
[root@### htdocs]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-5345_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 44.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 58.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 69.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 76.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 530.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 55.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php.rej
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 2672.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.rej
```

From what I've seen this is due to line endings, but I've double checked these and they are Unix. Has anyone come across this before is it something to do with nginx? Any advise would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue on a couple of patches. My solution was to just grab the files from a fresh copy of Magento, replace the modified files, and then apply the patch.

This should work fine so long as the modifications to those files are trivial (such as line ending issues). You should verify that there haven't been actual changes to the functionality of those core files.

Alternatively, you can find the already patched files here:

http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

You could just upload those over FTP. Personally I think it is better to use the shell patch as it is easy to roll back if something goes wrong.

Comment: That's great! thanks for your reply I'll try doing this manually. Have you ever found a source to the reason to have to do it manually?

Comment: No I didn't. I did a diff on the modified files vs the default magento files and they were identical (according to the diff). All of the sites I have encountered this issue with have been breached as a result of the vulnerability. I have a suspicion that attackers are making a trivial modification to the files to prevent the patch from being applied. Or it might just be a line ending issue.